# Deriving Riemannian Metric within Exponential Family of Distributions

Tags: fisher-information

I am reading a paper titled "Stochastic Variational Inference" by Hoffman et al. ([link](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume14/hoffman13a/hoffman13a.pdf)). I am trying to show this result (page 1316)
$$D_{KL}^{sym}(\lambda,\lambda + d\lambda)=O(||d\lambda||^3) + \mathbb{E}[(d\lambda^{\top}\nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda))^2],$$ 
and I simply cannot derive $O(||d\lambda||^3)$ term.

The authors first apply Taylor series expansions on $\log q(\beta|\lambda +d\lambda)$ and $q(\beta|\lambda +d\lambda)$ about $\lambda$. This yields
$$\log q(\beta| \lambda + d\lambda) = \log q(\beta|\lambda) + d\lambda^{\top}\nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda) + O (||d\lambda||^2),$$ (assuming that $d\lambda^2$ means Euclidean norm) and $$q(\beta| \lambda + d\lambda) = q(\beta| \lambda) + q(\beta| \lambda)d\lambda^{\top} \nabla_{\lambda} \log q(\beta|\lambda) + O(||d\lambda||^2).$$ Then applying the definition of symmetrized Kullback-Leibler divergence, we have
$$D_{KL}^{sym}(\lambda,\lambda + d\lambda) = \int_{\beta}\big[q(\beta|\lambda+d\lambda)-q(\beta|\lambda)\big]\big(\log q(\beta|\lambda + d\lambda) - \log q(\beta | \lambda)\big)d\beta.$$
Substituting for $ q(\beta|\lambda+d\lambda) - q(\beta|\lambda)$ and   $\log q(\beta|\lambda+d\lambda)-\log q(\beta|\lambda)$ using Taylor series expansion gives
$$D_{KL}^{sym}(\lambda,\lambda + d\lambda) = \int_{\beta}\big[q(\beta| \lambda)d\lambda^{\top} \nabla_{\lambda} \log q(\beta|\lambda) + O(||d\lambda||^2)\big]\big(d\lambda^{\top}\nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda) + O (||d\lambda||^2)\big)d\beta \\= \int_{\beta}q(\beta|\lambda)[d\lambda^{\top}\nabla_{\lambda}\log q (\beta| \lambda)]^2 d\beta + \int_{\beta}d\lambda^{\top} O(||d\lambda||^2) q(\beta|\lambda)\nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda)d\beta \\+\int_{\beta}O(||d\lambda||^2) d\lambda^{\top} \nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda)d\beta + \int_{\beta}O(||d\lambda||^2)O(||d\lambda||^2)d\beta.$$
Now, the integral in the second term evaluates to zero as
$$\int_{\beta} q(\beta|\lambda)  \nabla_{\lambda}\log q(\beta|\lambda)d\beta = \int_{\beta} q(\beta|\lambda)\big( T(\beta) - \nabla_{\lambda} a_{g}(\lambda)\big) d\beta=\mathbb{E}(T(\beta)) - \nabla_{\lambda} a_{g}(\lambda) = \nabla_{\lambda} a_{g}(\lambda) -\nabla_{\lambda} a_{g}(\lambda) = 0$$ where $T(\beta)$ is sufficient statistics and $a_{g}(\lambda)$ is the log-normaliser of the variational density $q(\beta|\lambda)$. Taken together, we have something like
$$d\lambda^{\top}O(||d\lambda||^2)*0.$$ Similarly, the third term also involves integral that evaluates to zero. Thus, can somebody please help me understand  how we are suppose to deduce that the contribution of these two terms is just $O(||d\lambda||^3)$? Is zero here interpreted in terms of a limit or it is taken as constant? I appreciate very much help with this.